# Adding card source works in 19.45.0, fails in 20.0.0 and above

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I am playing with Stripe-Java and I'm trying to add a card to a customer.

My code looks like this:

```
    Customer stripeCustomer = Customer.retrieve("cus_xxxxxxx");
    
    Map<String, Object> cardParam = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        cardParam.put("number", "4242424242424242");
        cardParam.put("exp_month", "11");
        cardParam.put("exp_year", "2022");
        cardParam.put("cvc", "123");
    
    //token
    Map<String, Object> tokenParam = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    tokenParam.put("card", cardParam);
    
    Token token = Token.create(tokenParam);
    
    //user token
    Map<String, Object> sourceParam = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    sourceParam.put("source", token.getId());
    
    //add to customer
    stripeCustomer.getSources().create(sourceParam);
```

This works successfully on Stripe-Java version 19.45.0 but not on 20.0.0 or any versions above. Has the method to add a card changed?

A nullpointer exception is thrown

Thanks

Comment: are you seeing any error?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?  Provide details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This :  `stripeCustomer.getSources()` will be null in v20.0.0 and above of the library because it pins to API version 2020-08-27 where `customer.sources` was removed by default. [0] [1]

> The sources property on Customers is no longer included by default.
> You can expand the list but for performance reasons we recommended
> against doing so unless needed.

You would need to explicitly expand [2] `"sources"` when retrieving the Customer in order to populate `customer.getSources()`

```
CustomerRetrieveParams params = CustomerRetrieveParams.builder()
        .addExpand("sources").build();
Customer stripeCustomer = Customer.retrieve("cus_xxxxxxx", params, null);
```

Also, your code uses the legacy Token API, and is passing raw card details from your server that puts you in PCI scope, you should look into the recommended integration paths : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

[0] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2000---2020-08-31

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-08-27

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/expand

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the comment about PCI compliance. This was just me testing the java api. I will be sure to follow the standards before publishing.